# Wordpress Error: "an error occurred while processing this directive". Debug.log output available

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Hope someone might be able to shed some light on this one.
The error is very generic and seems quite unpredictable.
Happens on some page loads, not others, and when it does, if you refresh a few times, page will load.

However, some pages just will not load at all however may times you refresh.
The site in question has been running 5 years with no issues like this.

I wanted to update it to WPv5.0 (from 4.9.8), so tried running a backup using 2 different WP plugins (such as readybackup), both backups stalled afetr being left for over an hour, so I just shut them down.
Error started after this.

Diagnosis/work done so far:

Uninstalled the 2 Backup plugins.
Disabled ALL plugins - site works fine.
Enabled plugins 1-by-1. All are up-to-date including Woocommerce and its database.
When WooCommerce activated the error messages appear again:an error occurred while processing this directive.
Ran the Wpress updater to v5.0 - ran ok without Woocommerce activated.
Ran update to the Genesis framework theme (Enterprise Pro child theme) to latest version 2.7.1 (Nov 2018 version) - updated ok without Woocommerce activated.

Ran a recursive script to check / change all files folder permissions: 0644 for files, 0755 for folders, output=o needed changing.Physically checked as well - random check of files and folders showed all permissions ok.

Re-loaded the default/standard/original .htaccess file for Wordpress.
Hit 'save' in permalinks in Wpress dashboard.

Activated Woocommerce, used the plugin tools to clear transient cache etc.. in database and re-created default woocomm pages (such as cart etc..) through their tools menu.
(all the while getting same error in between trying each function and refreshing webpage several times to get it to work).

Enabled debug log in wp-config.php.

Log output (line after line, of the SAME error only:

[11-Dec-2018 02:03:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (HY000/2013): Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /home1/alphxxxx/public_html/turbochargerxxxxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1924
MY NOTE: xxxx = hidden info.

If I download the wp-db.php file, and open in code editor notepad++ , from line 1909 to 1933 it shows:

```
 /**
 * Internal function to perform the mysql_query() call.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @see wpdb::query()
 *
 * @param string $query The query to run.
 */
private function _do_query( $query ) {
    if ( defined( 'SAVEQUERIES' ) && SAVEQUERIES ) {
        $this->timer_start();
    }

    if ( ! empty( $this->dbh ) && $this->use_mysqli ) {
        $this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query );
    } elseif ( ! empty( $this->dbh ) ) {
        $this->result = mysql_query( $query, $this->dbh );
    }
    $this->num_queries++;

    if ( defined( 'SAVEQUERIES' ) && SAVEQUERIES ) {
        $this->queries[] = array( $query, $this->timer_stop(), $this->get_caller() );
    }
}
```

Other Errors found:

In folder:  wp-content/uploads/

File:  wc-logs

2018-12-10T08:11:02+00:00 CRITICAL Class 'WP_Roles' not found in /home1/alphxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxxx/wp-settings.php on line 400

And below, an error that repeats itself, found in the same file as above:

2018-12-10T10:48:21+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/home1/alphxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxx/wp-content/wp-performance-score-booster): failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in /home1/alphxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/wp-performance-score-booster/uninstall.php:15
Stack trace:

## 0 /home1/alphxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/wp-performance-score-booster/uninstall.php(15): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/home1/alpxxxx...', 4096)

## 1 /home1/alphxxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/wp-performance-score-booster/uninstall.php(12): delete_storage_dir('/home1/alphxxx...')

## 2 /home1/alphxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxxx/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(1018): include('/home1/alphxxxx...')

## 3 /home1/alphxxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxxxxx/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(831): uninstall_plugin('wp-performance-...')

## 4 /home1/alpxxxx/public_html/turboxxxxxxxx/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php

Other error found error_log in folder: wp-content:

[22-Nov-2018 12:43:52 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
NOTE: this error was happening well before this issue so might not be related, but good to see if can also be resolved.?

Additionally:
My site is hosted with BlueHost and I found a plugin (called SSO.php) in the MU-plugin folder that THEY installed without my consent on Wpress sites hosted with them that force upgrades to sites (see article: https://wptavern.com/bluehost-open-sources-script-used-to-update-2-5-million-wordpress-sites). Unbelievable.
I believe from this cron, the site has tried to be backed up and at times automatically updated, failed and restored. I think this because files AND databases that I had deleted long ago seem to have re-appeared.
If I re-name the SSO plugin to inactivate it, I can't access ANY pages at all! and get the constant error: "an error occurred while processing this directive"
I believe this action by Bluehost may have somehow contributed to issues on the site. Needless to say, once I have fixed this issue I will be migrating OFF Bluehost!.

Sorry for the long spiel, but I really hope some PHP guru can nail this one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try to remove the plugin `wp-performance-score-booster` folder in FTP.

Comment: Thanks, it was removed prior to posting this, along with its folders and .htaccess file changes that the plugin had made to boost site speed (restored .htaccess to standard Wpress file)